# xaml c# checking if event is subscribed in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

I have done the research behind this, but the code doesn't quite do what I want it. basically I have created a ToolBar that only shows the Icons to the events that have been called in the parent window (xaml). So for example if I called the New_Click Event, then the New Button appears hiding all the rest.

```
    //NEW
    public event btnNew_ClickedEventHandler btnNew_Click;
    public delegate void btnNew_ClickedEventHandler(object sender);
    private void btnNew_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnNew_Click != null) {
            btnNew_Click(this);
            EnableIcons();
        }
    }
```

That would be the code the declare the event.

```
        //Check if Icon should be shown
        if (btnNew_Click != null & iconName == "New") {
            toolIcon.MouseUp += btnNew_MouseUp;
        }
```

This registers the event with the icon. Now for btnNew_Click i am null value, even though I have declared it correctly in the 1st block of code... any idea why??

Comment: btnNew_Click is null until there is a listener registered.

Comment: ok, what do you mean by then. In my xaml i have called btnNew_Click="method"

Comment: According to your question title, you want to know how to check an event subscription from XAML. But we don't see any XAML markup in your question, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an event has 0 subscribers, the event will stay null. As soon as you subscribe an event handler to your "btnNew_Click" it will no longer be null. You have declared your event and set it's event handler type to your delegate, now you need to subscribe to the event. You only need to check if the event is null right before you fire it. Because, there's no reason to fire an event, if there are no subscribers. It looks as though you just need to remove the null check from here:

```
    //Check if Icon should be shown
    if (iconName == "New") {
        toolIcon.MouseUp += btnNew_MouseUp;
    }
```

Comment: actually, i need to check if its null because there is a little logic at the end that disables (hides) the button. And i got this code to work in VB. I am thinking maybe it has something to do that I am calling this right after the InitializeComponent... where as in vb i was calling it in the Loaded. could that be a reason?

Comment: @user3524375, this is a bad approach to create some logic around a check whether an event has subscriptions. Basically, the event publisher doesn't need to know whether there are any event subscriptions at all, and if any, what for objects they are. If you have built your application logic around this, then I strongly suggest you to reconsider it.

Comment: I have a toolbar with say 20 icons, if the programmer just codes the ones he needs, and the toolbar will show those only. This way I can stamp out the same toolbar everywhere. Knowing this, how would you design it?

Comment: @user3524375, well, it depends. It might be a configuration XML file, or a resource configuration file, or a public property of a `[Flags] enum` type, or a bunch of dependency properties, or ... We need more information about what you try to achieve. And your question is a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). You might wish to improve it describing what you actually wish to implement.

Comment: ok, thats a valid point. I will try to re-analyze how it can be improved. thanks!